# Changing the screen brightness on Windows via the console

Tags: windows, winapi, autohotkey, screen-brightness

I am trying to write a simple console application for Windows 10 that changes the screen brightness. Ultimately, I want to use this application with AutoHotKey, but this is secondary.

In researching this, almost everything I found referred to Android, which doesn't help. I did find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811279/possible-to-change-screen-brightness-with-c) about changing the screen brightness with C, but unfortunately that is for Linux.

[This archived thread](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/83100-laptop-screen-brightness/) contains a script that (while appearing quite hacky) makes a good impression - but it

> is deprecated, and on many *[Systems]* it will not return the full brightness settings array. So, where you should have 8 levels, IOCTL_VIDEO_QUERY_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS will only return 6, or none at all. *(by jkiel, [1](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/83100-laptop-screen-brightness/))*

So I would prefer to use the `WmiMonitorBrightness` class ([2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmicoreprov/wmimonitorbrightness) [3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmicoreprov/wmimonitorbrightnessmethods)) over `IOCTL_VIDEO_QUERY_SUPPORTED_BRIGHTNESS`. It also provides a lot finer granularity, but I lack the skills to implement it correctly.

So how can I change the screen brightness on Windows 10? Possibly using the mentioned `WmiMonitorBrightness` class? I don't mind if it is a C application, an AutoHotKey script or something else, that I can control from console.

Comment: What language do you actually want to write this code in? Do you want to write it in C, and then call it from AutoHotKey? Or would you prefer a routine that works natively in AutoHotKey?

Comment: As it is not about speed, using C and compiling it to an .exe which is then called from AHK would be a feasible option. Unfortunately, I'm not able to use C just well enough and I found no native AHK option.

Comment: Related meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394492/4575793

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for a [solution](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/39004-how-to-adjust-display-brightness-im-sure-its-possible/page-2), I found [this software](http://web.archive.org/web/20180211085529/https://edgylogic.com/projects/display-brightness-vista-gadget/)  from 2008 which works like a charm for me on Windows 10. The developer provided the **C# source and compiled application** [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160830000255/http://edgylogic.com/dynmedia/292/). "You will need the *Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0* or greater for the app to work."

Plus it supports the full granularity of setting brightness on your screen.

> To use the console app, the following parameters are allowed:
>
> - DisplayBrightnessConsole.exe
>     *This will return the current brightness level.*
> - DisplayBrightnessConsole.exe -getlevels
>     *This will return all possible brightness levels accepted by the display, separated by a new line.*
> - DisplayBrightnessConsole.exe **20** (or some other brightness level number)
>     *This will set the brightness level of the display to the parameter given, in this case, 20.*
>
> The code currently only works on single-display systems. If your system has more than one display, it 
>   will only work on the first (generally primary) display. It should be fairly easy to modify it to support more.

---

Possibly helpful for people using python - but it doesn't help in my specific case:

[How can I detect brightness changes using Python and WMI on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59914907/how-can-i-detect-brightness-changes-using-python-and-wmi-on-windows-10)